# Create new database and table with Ruby and Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I'm switching from Sqlite to Mysql and I can't find much information on how to use mysql2 gem.

Is this the best way to create a new db and then a new table inside it?

```
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
client.query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test")
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :database => "test")
client.query("CREATE TABLE test(Nome TEXT, Valore INT)")
client.close
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after `:username => "root"`. `:username => "root", :database => "test"`

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo copying my script. The script works fine, I was asking if there is a better way to execute this task (creating a new db, and a new table inside it)

Comment: If you want to add an error handling. Wrapping the queries in `begin` and `rescue` blocks.